# Response from Web API : Failed to load resource : ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: c#

I have WEB API APP hosted on Azure App Service. Web API have some background process. It connects to DAX studio gets data and process it to get in the data required format. When there is huge data, it processes and produces the result successfully in local environment. But when I publish that in Azure App Service, in various environments, I am getting "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error and WEB API shows "error : no response from server" message in response header. I suspect this is happening due to timeout limitations on App Service. I have tried few settings in web.config for handling the timeout issue, but none of them worked. I also tried adding few environment variables in App Service configuration settings, but those too did not work. Any suggestions or help in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you are using some resource with https and your service doesn't support https. The certificate may also be invalid. Have you tried another browser to make sure, no extension like Adblocker or VPN is interfering with it.

Comment: This is a feature where I am exporting data to excel from Power BI reports. This is done using WEB API in c#, which is called on I am building a WEB API. This WEB API gets a call from Power BI button click. There are no additional resources used.

Comment: Well, I think there must be some resources because your title says it or is the title wrong?

Comment: This is a feature where I am exporting data to excel for large file using memory stream and there are no additional resources used and getting the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error.